# Write a JSON validator

Tags: code-golf

Write a program that determines whether its input is valid [JSON](http://json.org).

- **Input:** ASCII text: `[\x00-\x7F]*`

  *Note: if ASCII is problematic, feel free to use another encoding, but indicate it in your post.*
- **Output:** `Valid` or `Invalid`.  Trailing newline may be omitted.
- **Example:**

  ```
   $ echo '{"key": "value"}' | ./json-validate
   Valid
   $ echo '{key: "value"}' | ./json-validate
   Invalid
  ```
- **Rules:**

  - Do not use a JSON parsing library.
  - Partially-correct solutions are allowed, but frowned upon.
  - Post your test suite score (see below).

The **shortest correct** solution wins.

Please run [json-validate-test-suite.sh](https://raw.github.com/gist/3796234/json-validate-test-suite.sh) on your program, and post your score.  Example:

```
$ ./json-validate-test-suite.sh ./buggy-prog
fail: should be invalid:  [ 0.1e ] 
fail: should be invalid:  [ 0.1e+-1 ] 
fail: should be invalid:  [ 0.1e-+1 ] 
score: 297/300
```

**Resources:**

- [json.org](http://json.org/) - Concise definition of the JSON grammar with easy-to-follow pictures.
- [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) - JSON specification
- [json-validate.c](https://raw.github.com/gist/3796234/json-validate.c) - A 200-line implementation that passes the testsuite.

---

The JSON grammar is as follows:

```
json: object | array

object: '{' members? '}'
    members: pair (',' pair)*
    pair:    string ':' value

array: '[' elements? ']'
    elements: value (',' value)*

value: string
     | number
     | object
     | array
     | 'true'
     | 'false'
     | 'null'

string: '"' char* '"'
    char: [^"\\\x00-\x1F]
        | '\' escape
    escape: ["\\/bfnrt]
          | u [0-9A-Fa-f]{4}

number: '-'? (0 | [1-9][0-9]*) ('.' [0-9]+)? ([Ee] [+-]? [0-9]+)?
```

Also, whitespace can appear before or after any of the six structural characters `{}[]:,`

```
ws = [\t\n\r ]*
```

Bear in mind the following:

- Be careful with functions like `isspace()`.  Whitespace in JSON is `[\t\n\r ]`, but `isspace()` also treats `\v` (vertical tab) and `\f` (form feed) as space.  Although word has it that `isdigit()` can [accept more than just `[0-9]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898228/can-isdigit-legitimately-be-locale-dependent-in-c), should be okay to use here, as we assume input is in ASCII.
- `\x7F` is technically a control character, but the JSON RFC doesn't mention it (it only mentions `[\x00-\x1F]`), and most JSON parsers tend to accept `\x7F` characters in strings.  Because of this ambiguity, solutions may choose to either accept them or not.

Comment: Your "partially-correct solutions allowed" note is making me dream of extracting a regex from a genetic algorithm.  I must be insane.

Comment: @J B: That would be awesome.

Comment: Just curious, why is `{key: "value"}` consider invalid JSON ? It is valid javascript.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: I imagine it's so JSON will be easier to parse and less ambiguous to implementors.  I'm not sure I like this restriction either.

Comment: Anyone got a copy of the validator script?

Comment: @Alison: I fixed the links.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm going to close this question as unclear.  Back in the day we had a lot looser rules on clarity, but things have changed.  A more modern question would have to include an actual spec and couldn't have such as "partially-correct solutions allowed".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## PHP : <s>297</s> <s>285</s> <s>264</s> 253 characters

```
<?=preg_match(<<<'R'
~([\h
]*)({(?1)((("([^"\\\0- ]| |\\(["\\/bfnrt]|u[\dA-Fa-f]{4}))*")(?1):(?1)((?5)|-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?([Ee][+-]?\d+)?|(?2)|true|false|null))(((?1),(?1))(?4))*)?}|\[(?1)((?8)((?13)(?8))*)?(?1)])(?1)\z~A
R
,`cat`)?'Valid':'Invalid';
```

**score: 300/300**

This is a full, recursive implementation of the JSON grammar.

It works only on PHP ≥ 5.3 due to [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax (heredoc would have required to double all `\`).

Readable version:

(this is the same regex, with named capture groups and extended syntax):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$re = <<< 'RE'
~\A (?P<ws>[\t\n\r ])* (
    (?P<object>\{ (?P>ws)*
        (?P<members>
            (?P<pair>
                (?P<string>
                    "(?P<char>
                        [^"\\\x00-\x1F]
                        |\\(?P<escape>
                            ["\\/bfnrt]
                            |u [0-9A-Fa-f]{4}
                        )
                    )*"
                ) (?P>ws)* : (?P>ws)* (?P<value>
                    (?P>string)
                    | (?P<number>-? (0 | [1-9][0-9]*) (\. [0-9]+)? ([Ee] [+-]? [0-9]+)? )
                    | (?P>object)
                    | (?P>array)
                    | true
                    | false
                    | null
                )
            ) ( (?P>ws)* , (?P>ws)* (?P>pair) )*
        )?
    \})
    |(?P<array>\[ (?P>ws)*
        (?P<elements>
            (?P>value) ( (?P>ws)* , (?P>ws)* (?P>value) )*
        )?
    (?P>ws)* \])
) (?P>ws)* \z~x
RE;

if (preg_match($re, stream_get_contents(STDIN))) {
    echo 'Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

Comment: Wow. _` ` ` ` ` `_

Comment: You need to include the `<?php` IMO.

Comment: Added. 264 chars now :-)

Answer (score 6):

### Python - <s>340</s> <s>314</s> <s>299</s> 292 chars

```
import re,os
r=x=re.sub
z=r('0\.0+','0',r('e[+-]?0+|[\t\n\r]',' ',r(r'"(\\["nrtb\\/]|[^\\"\0-\37])*"','1',r(r'true|false|null|\\u\w{4}|[1-9]\d*','0',os.read(0,99)))))
while z!=x:z,x=r('\{(1:\d)?(,\\1)*\}|\[(-?\d(,-?\d)*)?\]','0',r(' *([][{}:,]) *','\\1',z)),z
print['Inv','V'][z=='0']+'alid'
```

score

```
$ ./json-validate-test-suite.sh ./codegolf-474.py
score: 300/300
```

Answer (score 3):

### Scala - 390 chars

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers
object J extends JavaTokenParsers{def j=o|a
def o:Parser[Any]="{"~repsep(p,",")~"}"
def p=s~":"~v
def a:Parser[Any]="["~repsep(v,",")~"]"
def v=s|o|a|"true"|"false"|"null"
def s=stringLiteral
def n=floatingPointNumber}
object Main{def main(a:Array[String]){print(if(J.parseAll(J.j,readLine()).successful)"Valid"else"Invalid")}}
```

This is no-brainer soluton, using parser combinators. Written in 1 or 2 minutes, literally. Cannot get validator script, browser said that server not found.

Comment: looks like an interesting solution; validator link has been fixed.

Comment: Is there a simple way to do it on Windows? (without cygwin or similar heresy)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 29 bytes

```bash
jq -r '"Valid"'||echo Invalid
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6BerVSWmFOaqmSloJSdWqlUq17zP6tQQbdIQV0pLDEnM0VJvaYGrNIzrwzE//8fAA)

TIO's bash instance conveniently has jq installed for us so try it online at your leisure!

Comment: This is not a valid answer because the program is expected to print `Valid` or `Invalid`, and any other output format is not allowed (i.e. jq alone can't solve this challenge). Always watch out for I/O formats when trying very old challenges.

Comment: Uh oh, thanks @Bubbler. I totally missed that! I'm surprised though that our current I/O standards don't apply. Do those only apply when I/O isn't already strictly defined?

Comment: Yes, I/O defaults only apply when the challenge doesn't specify the I/O. (Also, changing I/O rules for an existing challenge is fundamentally a breaking change, so we don't do that.)

Comment: Thanks bunches @Bubbler, I'll fix this right away!

Comment: (The only way to fix this answer is to delete it, since if you use something like Bash + jq, then jq surely counts as a "JSON parsing library" which is banned.)

Comment: @Bubbler Oh no, I've *just* done that! I don't think it's fair to consider jq a JSON parsing library, though. That's like calling a calculator a number parser. It turns out to be a convenient side effect of a simple calculator that it won't have any idea how to handle *'a1b2c3'*. Instead it'll error, but that's more of a bug than a feature :p A concrete example: `echo 1|bc`  runs successfully, whereas `echo 1a|bc` errors. But I wouldn't call using *bc* a 'number-parsing library'.

Comment: Of course jq can do much more than that, but the *first* thing it does is to parse JSON for you (and error if the input is not a valid JSON). And I'd interpret "JSON parsing library" as "anything that can parse JSON for you without effort", since "following the spirit of the challenge" was important in the old days.

Comment: @Bubbler But the rules say that "partially correct solutions are allowed but frowned upon". Doesn't that override the typical invalidity policy and make this answer not need to be deleted?

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal I believe the specific line is talking about not passing 100% of the test cases provided (which is a dead link now, btw). I'd say this is not a partially correct solution but a *rule-breaking* solution.

Comment: @Bubbler Oh, I missed that there was a test suite. I would say that the rule allowing partially correct solutions makes the challenge unclear, though, as there's no threshold for determining when an answer is correct enough to be valid, and it's not a [tag:test-battery].